# If a rotational value has a range of -1 to 1, how would I convert it to degrees?

Tags: data-conversion, 360-degrees

I have a camera in my 3D java game whose vertical axis can go from -1(looking straight down) to 1(looking straight up). If zero is looking straight ahead, then how might I convert this vertical axis value to degrees(0 - 360), with 0 being straight, -90 looking down, and +90 looking up? Thanks in advance!

Comment: erm .. multiply your value with 90?

Comment: Is it that simple? Sorry, I'll try that! I guess I assumed that it would be too complicated for something simple. Thanks!